# Проблемы с загрузкой obj-файлов в three.js

Tags: three.js, obj

THREE.js не грузит obj-файлы стандартным загрузчиком. Вот код:

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader(manager);
    loader.load('http://myWork/objects/obj4.obj', function ( object ) {
        //scene.add( object );
        alert('loaded');
    } );
```

При чтении файла выводит ошибку, что ему не нравится token #. Убрал # - не нравится буква v перед каждой вершиной. Какого тогда формата должен быть obj-файл?

Comment: На самом деле ответ очень прост. Просто я некачественный THREE.js скачал. Остерегайтесь дешёвых подделок. Кстати, для obj-файлов нужно ещё подгружать дополнительный класс, который входит в библиотеку THREE.js, а в "голом" THREE.js его нет. Забыл как называется класс.